# How to populate Dropdown with jQuery each() Loop

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select, populate

i want to to exactly the same like this:

```
window.onload = function populateDropdown(){
    console.log('Hallo i bims, ein Method')
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var select = document.getElementById('age');
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
    }
};
```

in jQuery.. i already tried it with $.each(), but i don't understand how i can do the the step:

```
(;i < 99; i++)
```

Can u give me some hints pls ?

Comment: `.each()` has will loop through all elements

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. In each iteration we're creating a new `option` element and setting both its `text` and `value` to `i`. Then we append it to the `select` with `.appendChild()`.

```js
window.onload = function populateDropdown(){
  var select = document.getElementById('age');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = i;
    option.value = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="age"></select>
```

Comment: Hey Gustaf, can you please tell me what should I do if I want to set as a default value and text of the select item with a number 6, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of `for` loop in `JQuery`:

```
var totalNumbers = 99;
for (var i = 0; i < totalNumbers; i++) {
  //creates option tag
  jQuery('<option/>', {
    value: i,
    html: i
  }).appendTo('#ID_OF_SELECT');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$.each() will loop through the selected elements (all the already existing elements only)

To achive this you'll need to use a for loop or alike.

```
for(var i = 0, i < 100; i++) {
    $('#age').append('<option/>', {
        value: i,
        html: i
    });
}
```